# Can't seem to line up decimal numbers precisely

Tags: c++, input, io, iomanip

I have a simple program that asks for the name of a film, and the amount of tickets sold for set1 and set2. Then it does some computation with those values and displays the results. The only issue I have is that I can't seem to line up the decimal values the way I want them to.

The last three lines of output in the console should look like this all the time (with the dollar signs AND decimal points lined up): [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/47z1bdyjkdlp32y/Screenshot%202015-09-13%2015.33.22.png?dl=0). But when I input 1 for set1 of tickets, and 0 for set2 of tickets and vice versa, it looks like this instead: [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wfmopyqfox6pgz/Screenshot%202015-09-13%2015.33.01.png?dl=0). Any ideas on how can I make the output ALWAYS line up nicely like in the first screenshot? Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

    string film = "";

    int set1 = 0;
    int set2 = 0;
    // the cinema always takes this 20% cut.
    const double CINEMA_FEE = 0.20;
    double profit = 0;
    double profitMinusFee = 0;
    double paidToMovieMaker = 0;

    cout << "What is the name of the film: ";
    getline(cin, film);

    cout << "How many tickets for set1 sold: ";
    cin >> set1;

    cout << "How many tickets for set2 sold: ";
    cin >> set2;

    cout << "Film Name:" << setw(20) << "\"" << film << "\"" << endl;
    cout << "Set1 tickets sold:" << setw(16) << set1 << endl;
    cout << "Set2 tickets sold:" << setw(16) << set2 << endl;

    set1 *= 10;
    set2 *= 6;
    profit = set1 + set2;
    profitMinusFee = profit * CINEMA_FEE;
    paidToMovieMaker = profit - profitMinusFee;
    // needs to always show two decimal points and fixed
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << "The total monetary profit:" << setw(5) << "$ " << profit << endl;
    cout << "The net monetary profit:" << setw(7) << "$ " << profitMinusFee << endl;
    cout << "Total paid to movie maker:" << setw(5) << "$ " << paidToMovieMaker << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you are setting the width on the dollar signs rather than your numbers.

This seems to fix it for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string film = "";

    int set1 = 0;
    int set2 = 0;
    // the cinema always takes this 20% cut.
    const double CINEMA_FEE = 0.20;
    double profit = 0;
    double profitMinusFee = 0;
    double paidToMovieMaker = 0;

    cout << "What is the name of the film: ";
    getline(cin, film);

    cout << "How many tickets for set1 sold: ";
    cin >> set1;

    cout << "How many tickets for set2 sold: ";
    cin >> set2;

    cout << "Film Name:" << setw(20) << "\"" << film << "\"" << endl;
    cout << "Set1 tickets sold:" << setw(16) << set1 << endl;
    cout << "Set2 tickets sold:" << setw(16) << set2 << endl;

    set1 *= 10;
    set2 *= 6;
    profit = set1 + set2;
    profitMinusFee = profit * CINEMA_FEE;
    paidToMovieMaker = profit - profitMinusFee;
    // needs to always show two decimal points and fixed
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << "The total monetary profit: $ " << setw(10) << profit << endl;
    cout << "The net monetary profit  : $ " << setw(10) << profitMinusFee << endl;
    cout << "Total paid to movie maker: $ " << setw(10) << paidToMovieMaker << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Remember `setw()` affects the thing that comes *after* it.

Comment: You nailed it. So simple, yet I missed it! Thank you sir.